# How to get XElement's value and not value of all child-nodes?

Tags: c#, xelement

Sample xml:

```
<parent>
<child>test1</child>
<child>test2</child>
</parent>
```

If I look for parent.Value where parent is XElement, I get "test1test2".
What I am expecting is "". (since there is no text/value for .

What property of XElement should I be looking for?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When looking for text data in the `<parent>` element you should look for child nodes that have [`NodeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.nodetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties equal to [`XmlNodeType.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). These nodes will be of type [`XText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The following sample illustrates this:

```
var p = XElement
    .Parse("<parent>Hello<child>test1</child>World<child>test2</child>!</parent>");

var textNodes = from c in p.Nodes()
                where c.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text
                select (XText)c;

foreach (var t in textNodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.Value);
}
```

**Update:** if all you want is the first Text node, if any, here's an example using LINQ method calls instead of query comprehension syntax:

```
var firstTextNode = p.Nodes().OfType<XText>().FirstOrDefault();
if (firstTextNode != null)
{
    var textValue = firstTextNode.Value;
    ...do something interesting with the value
}
```

**Note:** using `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` will be more performant than `Count() > 0` in this scenario. `Count` always enumerates the whole collection while `FirstOrDefault()` will only enumerate until a match is found.

Comment: What about CData sections? (XmlNodeType.CDATA)

Comment: @dtb - you find cdata sections as `XCData` nodes. You could easily extend the query to return both Text and CData.

Comment: I solved the problem pretty much your way... but your answer looks more elegant. My Code:  if (parent.Nodes() != null && parent.Nodes().OfType<XText>().Count() > 0)
    parentValue = parent.Nodes().OfType<XText>().First().Value;

Answer (score 9):

It is amazing that a coder somewhere at Microsoft thought that returning all text values as a concatenated and undelimited string would be useful.  Luckily, another MS developer wrote an XElement extension to return what they call the "Shallow Value" of the text node [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-retrieve-the-shallow-value-of-an-element).  For those who get the willies from clicking on links, the function is below...

```
    public static string ShallowValue(this XElement element)
    {
        return element
               .Nodes()
               .OfType<XText>()
               .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                          (s, c) => s.Append(c),
                          s => s.ToString());
    }
```

And you call it like this, because it gives you all the whitespace too (or, come to think of it, you could trim it in the extension, whatever)

```
// element is a var in your code of type XElement ...
string myTextContent = element.ShallowValue().Trim();
```

Comment: WOW! crazy cray cray that this was considered. `Value` should be current element. `ToString()` or `some other value` should be current element + children elements.

Answer (score 8):

You could concatenate the value of all `XText` nodes in `parent`:

```
XElement parent = XElement.Parse(
    @"<parent>Hello<child>test1</child>World<child>test2</child>!</parent>");

string result = string.Concat(
    parent.Nodes().OfType<XText>().Select(t => t.Value));

// result  ==  "HelloWorld!"
```

For comparison:

```
// parent.Value  ==  "Hellotest1Worldtest2!"

// (parent.HasElements ? "" : parent.Value)  ==  ""
```

Comment: `Concat` cannot give he expected result, since it won't concat the strings in the list, but the _type name_ of its parameter, here an `IEnumerable` of strings. `string.Join("", element.Nodes().OfType<XText>().Select(t => t.Value).ToArray());` is probaby what you need instead.

Answer (score 1):

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value.aspx) says:

> A String that contains all of the text content of this element. If there are multiple text nodes, they will be concatenated.

So the behaviour is to be expected.

You could solve your problem by doing:

```
string textContent = parent.HasElements ? "" : parent.Value;
```

Comment: What about mixed content elements? e.g. `<parent>Hello<child>test1</child>World<child>test2</child>!</parent>`

Comment: @dtb: parent contains 2 Child children and 2 TextNode children.

Comment: consider my mind boggled. I didn't know that this was allowed in xml.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create the XElement
XElement parent = XElement.Parse(
    @"<parent>Hello<child>test1</child>World<child>test2</child>!</parent>");

// Make a copy
XElement temp=new XElement(parent);

// remove all elements but root
temp.RemoveNodes();

// now, do something with temp.value, e.g.
Console.WriteLine(temp.value);
```