# Display the content of an XML file, sans tags, inside a WPF textblock/box

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file taken from an RSS feed, saved locally, and I simply want to display the contents of this XML file (without the tags) inside a textbox or a textblock - something to just display it to the user.

I have already written a method which loops through the whole XML file getting each section of information from the relevant tags and storing it all into a list. Is there any simple way for me to either just display the contents of my newly generated list inside a textbox? Or even just a method of displaying the full XML file itself without the tags would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: TextBox, TextBlock, or ListBox same answer - they only display string.  Create a public property that is a string representation of the object and bind to the property with the ListBox approach I recomfended or use the loop from codesparke to call that property.  If you use the loop you can call a method but to bind the ListBox is has to be a public property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to add each item from your List to the TextBlock. (You said you've already removed the tags from this list, correct?)

XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="rssDisplayer" />
```

C#:

```
private void displayListInTextBlock(List<Item> items)
{
    foreach (Item item in items)
    {
        rssDisplayer.Text += item.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

in `Item.cs`, you need to override `ToString()`. Because you haven't told us about your `Item` class, I'll make a rough guess here:

```
public class Item
{
    private string content; //just an example
    public override String ToString()
    {
        return content;
    }
}
```

If, however, you need help with removing the XML tags, take a look at [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251215/how-to-get-xelements-value-and-not-value-of-all-child-nodes).

Comment: Yeah, I have removed the tags already. The list I have created actually contains a number of objects, rather than strings. Each item within the XML file has been used to create an Item object and this object is then stored in the list. Is it still possible to use a loop as above to grab the contents of each object and display these?
If it's of any use, I am actually using Linq to XML to create this list of Item objects.

Comment: Maybe build up the text using StringBuilder then bind it once for speed.

Comment: @Beerlol I've edited my answer to accommodate an `Item` class. Yours will look a bit different, so you'll need to adjust it to suit your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the pertinent information in a List string then you could just bind that to a ListBox and you can format the ListBox to look like a textbox.   For some large text files I display I break them out by EOL into List string to display in a ListBox for virtulization.