# Create object from element name and value of xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have following the XML. It has element nodes and text in it.  I have to create object of the following class for each `element` node (only). The name of the element and its value need to be stored in the object. How can I do that?

```
    public class MyElement
    {
        public string ElementName { get; set; }
        public string ElementValue { get; set; }
    }
```

**CODE**

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {

        XDocument pDoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<main>
                                             Direct 1
                                            <sub1>A</sub1>
                                             Direct 2
                                            <sub2>B</sub2>
                                            <sub3>C</sub3>
                                             00
                                         </main>");



        IEnumerable<XNode> nodes = from c in pDoc.Elements().Nodes()
                                      select c;

        IEnumerable<MyElement> entityCollection = nodes.Select(v => new MyElement()
                             {
                                ElementName = v.ToString()
                             }).ToList();


    }
```

Required result will look like the following

```
List<MyElement> sampleRequiredList = new List<MyElement>();
sampleRequiredList.Add(new MyElement() { ElementName = "sub1", ElementValue = "A" });
sampleRequiredList.Add(new MyElement() { ElementName = "sub2", ElementValue = "B" });
sampleRequiredList.Add(new MyElement() { ElementName = "sub3", ElementValue = "C" });
```

**UPDATE**

Following is the solution based on the selected answer.

```
        var elementsUsingRoot = pDoc.Root.Elements();
        var nodesUsingRoot = pDoc.Root.Nodes();

        var secondCollection = pDoc.Root.Elements()
                      .Select(x => new MyElement
                      {
                          ElementName = x.Name.LocalName,
                          ElementValue = x.Value
                      });


        //Text Nodes
        IEnumerable<XText> textNodes = from c in pDoc.Root.Nodes()
                                       where c.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text
                                       select (XText)c;

        //Element Nodes
        IEnumerable<XElement> elementNodes = from c in pDoc.Root.Nodes()
                                             where c.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element
                                             select (XElement)c;


        //Element Nodes 2
        IEnumerable<XElement> elementNodes2 = from c in pDoc.Root.Elements()
                                              select c;
```

REFERENCE

1. [How to get XElement's value and not value of all child-nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251215/how-to-get-xelements-value-and-not-value-of-all-child-nodes)
2. [Best way to create entity objects from xml using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380694/best-way-to-create-entity-objects-from-xml-using-linq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
var entityCollection = doc.Root
                          .Elements()
                          .Select(x => new MyElement {
                                           ElementName = x.Name.LocalName,
                                           ElementValue = x.Value
                                       });
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why `XText` are not retrieved when `doc.Root` is called? That is the point I am not clear about, now.

Comment: @Lijo: What do you mean? `XText` nodes *aren't* elements.

Comment: I get `XText` also in the following query `from c in pDoc.Elements().Nodes() select c;`. So, I expected `XText` in the result of `doc.Root.Elements()`

Comment: @Lijo: No, precisely because they're text nodes, not elements. If you used `doc.Root.Nodes()` you'd get them.